# how to create smoke, fog in blender 3.0 cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

do any one knows any way of creating the smoke or fog that is in the below pic [image]

thanks

Comment: You can use this website for actual tutorial of how to make smoke in blender
https://tutorialguru1.blogspot.com/2023/02/how-to-make-smoke-in-blender.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make a "box" surrounding your scene, then use a Noise Texture + ColorRamp as the Density input for a Volume Scatter Node connected to the "box's" volume socket:

[image: Car2]

I used a (long rectangular) area light pointed straight up at the back of the plane to "light up" the back. Take note that you can increase the detail of the volume (at the cost of performance) by changing the settings underlined on the right (for "tile size", smaller is more detailed). You can also increase the detail by lowering the "end" value, bud don't go too low, as this is related to camera position.

Comment: awesome....!!!!! that's the best smoke tutorial in 15 secs i ever saw!